# Check element is both defined and has a non zero length using ngIf

Tags: angular

In an Angular app we retrieve via a service call a list of users. If the user list is empty, we store in our state store an empty array `[]`.

In the component we want to display the user list. We use the async pipe. We don't want to display the user list if the async call is not completed or fails, and if the length of user list is zero.

Here is the component html code at the moment:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="users$ | async as users">
  <ul *ngIf="users.length > 0">
    <li *ngFor="let user of users">{{user.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</ng-container>
```

Is there any way to combine the two `ngIf` checks in one statement. It appears to be a problem since we need to use the value `users` defined firstly using `as` keyword.

Something like:

`*ngIf="users$ | async as users && users.length > 0"` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In issue [#15481](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15481#issuecomment-289196353) on Angular GitHub, the question was asked about the `as` syntax:

> Can I use "as" in ngIf statement and get its property as a condition to
>   ngIf?

The answer given by [Dzmitry Shylovich](https://github.com/DzmitryShylovich) was:

> Nope

---

One way of condensing it in a single `ngIf` condition was suggested by [Arlo White](https://github.com/arlowhite) in issue [#16173](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16173#issuecomment-295446361): mapping the value to `null` if the list is empty. That method is shown in **[this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gcnehu)**.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="users$ | async as users">
```

```
this.users$ = usersObservable.map(x => x.length > 0 ? x : null);
```

Comment: That's indeed a nice solution. Will dig into it thanks.